# Docker: MariaDB со временем становиться недоступна

Tags: windows, docker, mariadb

Запулил `image` с `mariadb` и запустил его:

`docker run --name mariadb -p 3306:3306 -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -d mariadb/server:10.3`

Все работает - я могу подключиться как через `docker exec`, так и с `Java` кода.
Но после некоторого времени работы с бд, `Java` код и `IntelijIDEA` отказываются подключаться к БД. Хотя через `docer exec` все работает как обычно. Система `Windows 10`. Может винда что-то порит?

Comment: Уверен даже в винде docker умеет выводить логи контейнера. Попробуйте выполнить `docker logs mariadb` после того, как подключение пропало.

Comment: `docker exec` и подключение к базе это разные вещи. Вы пересоздете образ или после перезапуска все рабртает снова? Может быть проблема с наличием свободного места в образе.